# How to add images to an atom feed in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss, atom-feed

In a Rails 3.2 app I have a Photo model with a `:caption` field and using Carrierwave to handle image files.

I'm trying to create an atom feed that contains the images. What is the correct way to do this?

Currently I have

```
#views/photos/index.atom.builder
atom_feed do |feed|
  feed.title "Photos"
  @photos.each do |photo|
      feed.entry photo do |entry|
        entry.title photo.title
        entry.summary photo.caption
        entry.image image_path(photo.file.url(:large))
        entry.author do |author|
          author.name photo.user.name
        end
      end
    end
end
```

and while this does add an image tag to the feed markup, I think this may not be the correct syntax?

```
<entry>
   ...
   <image>http://path/to/image.jpg</image> 
   ...
</entry>
```

Else where I've seen the following syntax

```
<entry>
    <content type="image/jpg" src="/path/to/image.png" />
</entry>
```

I'd appreciate if someone with more knowledge could tell me:

1. What is the correct markup for incorporating images in an atom feed?
2. How do I generate that markup via the atom/xml builder in Rails?

Comment: Hi Holger, I did find an answer. But in the end I decided to go with an RSS feed instead of Atom - this is very specifc to my usage, as I needed to manipulate the feed for another purpose. Of the top of my head I can't remember what I did with Atom, but I do know that I worked out syntax to display the image inline (img tag) or as an attachment. I used Flickr's feed as a reference for structure. Let me know how you get on, and I can dig through my code tomorrow if you don't manage to get anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I also found a solution. Switched over to the RSS feed and embedded the image as an image tag in the description. Bit of a tweaky method but it works.

Comment: In case it helps, you can add images to your feed as enclosures/ attachements as follows: `xml.media :content, url: image_model.file.url(:fullpage), type:"image/jpeg", height:770, width:770` or `xml.media :thumbnail, url: image_model.file.url(:thumb), height: 50, width:50`. (I'm using carrierwave, you may need to construct your image paths differently. I'm not sure if/ what restrictions apply to height and width). YOu may also need to add some attributes to the top of your feed e.g `"xmlns:media" => "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"`

Answer (score 8):

I found an answer to my own question.

For Atom feeds, the image can be added to the content within img tags.

Alternatively it can be added as an enclosure:

```
feed.entry photo do |entry|
    entry.link href: photo.file.url(:large), rel:"enclosure", type:"image/jpeg" 
end
```

In the end I switched from Atom to RSS feed (this is peculiar to my use, as I needed to manipulate the feed later and found RSS easier to do this).

Again images can be added to RSS within the content tags as an img.

Or can be added as enclosures:

```
@photos.each do |photo|
    xml.item do
        xml.media :content, url: photo.file.url(:fullpage), type:"image/jpeg", height:770, width:770
        xml.media :thumbnail, url: photo.file.url(:thumb), height: 50, width:50
    end
end
```

For constructing RSS feeds like this, it may be necessary to add some attributes to the head of the RSS feed.

Mine looks like this

```
xml.instruct! :xml, version: "1.0" 
xml.rss version: "2.0", "xmlns:media" => "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/", "xmlns:atom" => "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" do
...
```

Comment: I tried adding the image to the content for Atom feeds as follows: entry.content "<img src=#{resource.image.url(:medium)} width='280', height='180'>".html_safe, :type => 'html' but it does not render the html tags any ideas?

Comment: what is rendered if you put `entry.content "<img src='http://twitter.com/images/resources/twitter-bird-light-bgs.png'/>", :type => "html"`

Comment: <content type="html">&lt;img src='http://twitter.com/images/resources/twitter-bird-light-bgs.png'/&gt;</content>

Comment: what are you seeing with your original post?` entry.content "<img src=#{resource.image.url(:medium)} width='280', height='180'>".html_safe, :type => 'html' `

Comment: Same problem the <img tags are not being rendered as html

Comment: if the problem is the escaped html tags, you might try using something like `entry.content image_tag(resource.image.url(:medium)).html_safe, :type => 'html'`. I'm not able to test this at present, so let me know what you see

Comment: <content type="html">&lt;img alt="Medium" height="180" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/agile_designer_uploads/images/789/medium.jpg?1355829775" width="280" /&gt;</content>

Comment: figured it out my content was not valid atom feed. Once I could validate it it worked